# Swiftのhyperoslo/ImagePickerを使うと落ちます。

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

`https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker`
を使うと落ちます。

開発環境
Xcode 10.2 (10E125)
Deployment Target: 12.2

その他必要な情報があれば教えてください。

```
import UIKit
import ImagePicker

class ViewController: UIViewController, ImagePickerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func addBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        choosePicture()
    }

    @objc func choosePicture() {
        let config = Configuration()
        config.doneButtonTitle = "Finish"
        config.noImagesTitle = "Sorry! There are no images here!"
        config.recordLocation = false
        config.allowVideoSelection = true

        let imagePicker = ImagePickerController(configuration: config)
        imagePicker.delegate = self

        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)//<-###ここで落ちる
    }

    // MARK: - ImagePickerDelegate
    func cancelButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController) {
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func wrapperDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {
        guard images.count > 0 else { return }

        print(images)
    }

    func doneButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: おそらくインストールに失敗していますね。コンソールにもっと具体的なエラーメッセージなど出ていませんか？どのようにフレームワークをインストールしましたか？

Comment: ありがとうございます！コンソールを見ておりませんでした。Info.plistに`Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description`と`Privacy - Camera Usage Description`を追加したら解決しました！回答として載せた方がいいでしょうか？

Comment: プライバシーの設定でライブラリアクセスの使用許可が必要というやつですね。確かにそれは頭から抜けていました。ぜひ自己回答してください。

Comment: どうもありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Info.plistに

```
Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
```

と

```
Privacy - Camera Usage Description
```

を追加したら解決しました！